# phpunit Mock returns null while original method returns string

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have this file structure:

```
- module
-- phpunit.xml
-- blaat.php
-- tests
--- blaatTest.php
```

contents of blaat.php

```
class Blaat
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        return 'my return value';
    }
}
```

contents of tests/blaatTest.php

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

require_once './blaat.php';

class blaatTest extends TestCase
{ 
    public function testCanBeCreatedFromValidEmailAddress(): void
    {
        $stub = $this->createMock(Blaat::class);

        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stub->doSomething());
    }
}
```

contents of phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
        bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="unit">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory suffix=".php">vendor</directory>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

When I run `phpunit` in my terminal (when I'm in the `modules` folder) I get this:

```
PHPUnit 6.0.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                     1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 427 ms, Memory: 22.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) blaatTest::testCanBeCreatedFromValidEmailAddress
Failed asserting that null matches expected 'foo'.

/path/to/module/tests/blaatTest.php:19

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

How is this possible? My method will always return a string, yet phpunit says it gets a null value as a return.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the doc [(Chapter 9. Test Doubles)](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html):

> By default, all methods of the original class are replaced with a
>   dummy implementation that just returns null (without calling the
>   original method). Using the `will($this->returnValue())` method, for
>   instance, you can configure these dummy implementations to return a
>   value when called

So this is the default behaviour, you need to instrument by yourself.

Comment: aaah, so I don't need to use a mock when testing the response of my methods? That explains a lot.

Comment: Yes, you should mock only the object that interact with the `class under test`

Comment: Ehm, sorry. I don't understand that. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Sorry for my english, I mean that you should use mock object and expectation only for mock the dependency of the class you are testing.

Comment: Could you please give an example? I'm really new to phpunit and I know next to nothing about it. So it's probably my lack of knowlegde and not your english why I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

This question might be old and as much as there is an answer that has been marked as correct which is theoretically. Below is a sample of a test case that does what is suggested by @Matteo.

```
use Silex\Application;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Ementor\Foundation\ApplicationFactory;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class ApplicationFactoryTest extends TestCase
{
   /**
    * @test
    */
   public function it_can_return_a_silex_object()
   {
      $factory = $this->getMockBuilder(ApplicationFactory::class)
          ->setMethods(array('create'))
          ->getMock();

       $factory->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
          ->method('create')
          ->willReturnCallback(function(){
              return new Application();
          });

       $this->assertInstanceOf(HttpKernelInterface::class, $factory->create());
    }
 }
```

In my case I repeated the logic that can be found within the original class. Hope this helps someone else out there who stumbles upon this question as I just did.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are building a test in Drupal. I have found the situations where a long constructor needs to be mocked, as it contains arguments that we don't care. Your implementation is correct, although you lack ->setMethods(NULL)

See an example of webp module which I am maintainer:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\Tests\phpunit_example\Unit;
use Drupal\Core\Image\ImageFactory;
use Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase;
use Drupal\webp;

class WebpTest extends UnitTestCase {
  protected $webp;
  /**
   * Before a test method is run, setUp() is invoked.
   * Create new unit object.
   */
  public function setUp() {
    // Mock the class to avoid the constructor.
    $this->webp = $this->getMockBuilder('\Drupal\webp\Webp')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->setMethods(NULL)
      ->getMock();
  }

  /**
   * @covers Drupal\webp\Webp::getWebpFilename
   */
  public function testgetWebpFilename() {
    $this->assertEquals("testimage.webp", $this->webp->getWebpFilename("testimage.jpg"));
    $this->assertEquals("testimage2.webp", $this->webp->getWebpFilename("testimage2.jpg"));
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't `require_once './blaat.php';` contains two dots .. like this `require_once '../blaat.php';` in tests/blaatTest.php?

If I understand your directory structure `blaat.php` is in another (upper) directory, but you are referencing the current directory.

Comment: Nope, that another error: `atal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../blaat.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /` So that is working fine